# Run a javascript function after a wordpress shortcode executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

So i have a shortcode that creates a filtered dropdown, as well as adds 6 custom blog posts. I have some javascript that i want to add after all the dom elements get added. How do i do that. I really just want invoke a javascript function post shortcode execution. Do i just set a timer and once something is found do it, or is there a bit better approach to this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  /* CREATE ISOTOPE on init */
  window.$announcement_isotope = jQuery('.announcement_section').isotope();
  window.$announcement_isotope.isotope({
    // Isotope options
    itemSelector: '.post_grid',
    resizable: true,
    layoutMode: "fitRows",
    transformsEnabled: false,
    isOriginLeft: jQuery( '.rtl' ).length ? false : true
  });
});
```

I am getting an error because it can't found .announcement_section because that is being created in the shortcode.

this is the shortcode code:

```
function render_announcement_section($atts){
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'term'      => '',
), $atts ) );

/***********GET PARENT Filters' ID*********/
$parentTerm=get_term_by('slug',$term,'category');
$parentID = $parentTerm->term_id;

/***************** FILTER ********************/
$filter_output .= '<div id="search-container">
                        <form class="form-wrapper cf">
                            <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search here..." required>
                            <button class="fa fa-search" type="submit"></button>
                        </form>   
                    </div>';


$filter_output .= '<div class="filter_wrapper">';
$filter_output .= '<div class="filter_header">Filter By';
$filter_output .= '<div class="updateButton">Update</div>';
$filter_output .= '</div>'; // filter_header


// FLOATING OBJECTS
$filter_output .= '<div class="filterDivider"></div>';

// Include the post categories as css classes for later useage with filters
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 'true',
        'exclude' => array(1,190),
    )
);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    $filter_output .= '<div class="filter_container filter_category" >';
    $filter_output .= '<h4>Topics</h4>';
    $filter_output .= '<ul class="filters">';
    foreach ( $terms as $child_term ) {
        $filter_output .= '<li class="filter"><label><input type="checkbox" value="'.$child_term->slug.'">'.$child_term->name.'</label></li>';
    }
    $filter_output .= '<li class="filter_all"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Select All">Select All</label></li>';

    $filter_output .= '</ul>';
    $filter_output .= '</div>'; // END OF .filter_container

};

$types = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
        'orderby' => 'none',
    )
);

if ( ! empty( $types ) && ! is_wp_error( $types ) ){
    $filter_output .= '<div class="filter_container filter_tag">';
    $filter_output .= '<h4>Types</h4>';
    $filter_output .= '<ul class="filters">';
    foreach ( $types as $type ) {
        $filter_output .= '<li class="filter filter-announcements '.$type->slug.'"><label><input type="checkbox" value="'.$type->slug.'">'.$type->name.'</label></li>';
    }
    $filter_output .= '<li class="filter_all"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Select All">Select All</label></li>';
    $filter_output .= '</ul>';
    $filter_output .= '</div>'; // END OF .filter_container

};
$filter_output .= '</div>'; // end of .filter_wrapper
/*********** POSTS ****************/
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category__in'      => array(187,186,183,182,184),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'paged'             => get_query_var('paged')
);

$cpt_query= new WP_Query($args);
$output .= '<div class="announcement_container">'; // OUTER CONTAINER
$output .= $filter_output;
$output .= '<div class="announcement_section announcment_section_'.$term.'">';
foreach ( $cpt_query->posts as $post )
{

    $output .= post_factory($post);

}
$output .= '</div>'; // END of .announcment_section
$output .= '</div>'; // END of OUTER CONTAINER .announcement_container

wp_reset_query();

return $output;

}
add_shortcode('add_announcement_section', 'render_announcement_section');
```

Here is the shortcode i use to add JS file to each page independently.

```
function add_js_from_theme_folder( $atts )
{   
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  ), $atts));

  foreach($atts as $value)
  {
    $return_string .='<script type="text/javascript" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/'.$value.'"></script>';
  }

  return $return_string;
}
add_shortcode( 'add_js', 'add_js_from_theme_folder');
```

Here is the website giving me issues : http://www.challenger.org/news-and-media/

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Shortcodes are parsed and executed via PHP. If the `.announcement_section` classname doesn't exist when the page is generated then is it added via javascript based on the output of the shortcode?

Comment: so the .annoucement_section gets created in the shortcode (did that answer your question?)

Comment: I see the question has been updated with the code that makes the shortcode and that does answer my question. From what I can see here it does output the `.announcement_section` class (and it would do so before the page was served) so the jQuery code should be able to find it in the markup without waiting on anything loading. Unless something else is acting on the `.announcement_section` after the page is served I cannot see why this would not work. A link to a live preview would be very useful here to see what happens on page load.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is that i'm adding my JS via shortcode as well. as i edited above. Could this be causing the problem. I really didn't want to enqueue every JS file i have for every page so i thougth this was a sleek workaround. Could this be causing my issue? I also added the URL, hope that will help.

Answer (score 2):

Well my biggest issue was thh enqueueing of JS files. Turns out if i register all my js files from the beginning and then just enqueue them in a shortcode when i need them it all works out marvelously. Than you William Patton for walking me through this, i guess i just needed to talk it out!

```
//Register
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'avada-parent-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_register_script( 'news-and-media', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/news_and_media.js');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
// ENQUEUE
function enqueue_js( $atts )
{   
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  ), $atts));

  foreach($atts as $value)
  {
    wp_enqueue_script($value);
  }

}
add_shortcode( 'add_js_handle', 'enqueue_js');
// [add_js_handle val1="news-and-media" val2="etc"]
```

Comment: You are very welcome, @Bardsworth. Glad talking through things a little with you helped out as figuring out the problem yourself is probably a lot more beneficial than someone simply providing the solution :)